# Meadian of subcategories within a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Is there a way to compute the median of subcategories that are within a column,

for example,

```
 Education
 primary
 secondary
 secondary
 tertiary
 primary
 unknown
```

so now I want to get the median count of primary, secondary, tertiary, unknown categories in the column
please help me with the codes in pandas.

[data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFKMi.jpg)
[the Subcategories(count) whose median I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/699Mo.jpg)

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your data?

Comment: I have shared the screenshot please look into it @LukasMuijs

Comment: My objective is to add a new line which is the median of each column i,e a graph which is simply,
y1=df[df['Education']=='primary'].meadian()
y2=df[df['Education']=='secondary'].meadian()
...... and so on for tertiary and unknown also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I was able to resolve the issue after some time here's the code I used

df1=df['education'].value_counts()
df2=pd.Series(df['education'].value_counts()).values
sns.countplot(x='education',data = df) 
plt.axhline(y=df2[0]/2, color='#e1812c', linestyle='-')
plt.axhline(y=df2[1]/2, color='#3274a1', linestyle='-')
plt.axhline(y=df2[2]/2, color='#3a923a', linestyle='-')
plt.axhline(y=df2[3]/2, color='#c03d3e', linestyle='-')
```

[Plot result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9so2.png)